# Error:Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside NavigationContainer?

Tags: react-native

App.js

```
<NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2}/> 
    </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Home.js

```
const navigation = useNavigation();

  const onTestPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Screen2'); // Navigate to Screen2
};
<Card.Actions>
          <Button
            style={{ width: 150, backgroundColor: "black" }}
            onPress={onTestPress}
          >
            See More..
          </Button>
 </Card.Actions>
```

Screen2

```
const Screen2 = () => {
  return (
    <View>
     Screen 2
    </View>
  )
}
```

I need to navigate Screen 2 page afterward Click 'See More' Button. But show the above error that i mentioned.

Comment: Your home screen should be put into `<NavigationContainer>` in App.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the **Home** screen inside `<NavigationContainer>` like below:

```
<NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2}/> 
    </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Thanks